# Why is a compact codomained function with compact fibers closed?

Tags: general-topology, compactness

Let $Y$ be a compact topological space and $f:X \rightarrow Y$ a function such that
\begin{equation}
f^{-1}(y) \text{ is compact in } X \quad \forall y \in Y,
\end{equation}

i.e. [fibers](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fiber_(mathematics)) are compact. Then $f$ is a [closed](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Open_and_closed_maps) function.

Why?

[Source](https://arcipelago.ml/res/manetti.jpg) of the statement is theorem 4.44 from Marco Manetti's "Topologia" coursebook.

EDIT: the theorem reported there is false, and it has been [fixed](https://arcipelago.ml/res/manetti-errata-corrige.png) in a later version
of the book (ISBN 8847007569,9788847007567).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The result is false. Let $X=[0,1]$ with the discrete topology, let $Y=[0,1]$ with the usual topology, and let $f$ be the identity map. Then $f$ has compact fibres, $Y$ is compact, and $f$ is certainly not closed, since, for instance, $(0,1)$ is closed in $X$ but not in $Y$.

Comment: I agree with you. Then I'm confused because the results [comes](https://arcipelago.ml/res/manetti.jpg) from a topology book (I'll give you the exact name tomorrow, I am not personally reading it).

It gives it as a fact on the third line: *Since $Y - A' = f(X \setminus A)$ and $f$ is closed it follows that if $A$ is open $A'$ is open.*

Comment: ISBN of the book is 8847007569,9788847007567, theorem is 4.41 on that edition.

Comment: @ScroogeMcDuck: **Teorema** $\mathbf{4.44}$ is simply false: the example in my answer is a counterexample to the theorem itself, even if *applicazione* here means *continuous function* (rather than just *function*): $Y$ is compact, and $X$ is not.

Comment: Agreed. Apparently the theorem was [corrected](https://arcipelago.ml/res/manetti-errata-corrige.png) in a later edition of the book (here theorem 4.41). Now the closedness of the function is in the hypothesis. I guess I have to tell the person who asked me the question to upgrade his book.

Comment: And where is the mistake in the proof? Unfortunately, no soy capable de hablare Italiano. ;-)

Comment: @ScroogeMcDuck: Yep; looks like *chiusa* was accidentally dropped in the earlier edition.

Comment: @amsmath it uses the fact that the function is closed without requiring it in the hypothesis.

Comment: @amsmath: The proof given in the earlier edition is fine if the map is closed, as it apparently was intended to be.

Comment: @BrianM.Scott Ah. So, una applicazione fermado.

Comment: @amsmath I was indeed wondering if it was possible to report  on MSE notions in many languages (for search engine indexing purposes), because for example *lattice* is translated as *insieme ordinato diretto in senso crescente*, so it is somehow difficult to find lol

Comment: @ScroogeMcDuck :DDD

Comment: @ScroogeMcDuck: I usually use Wikipedia by finding the appropriate article in English and then switching to the corresponding article in the target language (assuming that there is one). Doing that with *lattice*, for instance, takes me to **Reticolo (matematica)**: In matematica, un reticolo (*lattice* in inglese) è un insieme parzialmente ordinato in cui ogni coppia di elementi ha sia un estremo inferiore (**inf**) che un estremo superiore (**sup**). What you have there looks like it’s probably the translation of *directed set*, which is what you actually meant in your answer.

Comment: Yes, that's what I usually do, but I feel like doing it could impoverish non-english speaking users in the long run, since fewer and fewer people will try to convey meanings with synthentic expressions in their native language (btw I found those definition on an old book (Kantorovich-Akilov); there it call [*insieme ordinato in senso crescente*](https://arcipelago.ml/res/directed-sets.jpg) directed sets and [*insieme diretto*](https://arcipelago.ml/res/nets.jpg) nets).

Answer (score 0):

(This proof is already known to be wrong, please don't downvote.)

#### Requirements

**Directed set**

A set $A$ is said to be a [directed set](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Directed_set) if and only if for every $\alpha_1$, $\alpha_2 \in A$ there exists $\alpha \in A$ such that $\alpha > \alpha_1$ and $\alpha > \alpha_2$.

**Net**

Let $X$ be a set. A function from $A$ to $X$ is called [net](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Net_(topology)) and is denoted with the symbol $\{x_\alpha\}_{\alpha \in A}$.

**Convergent net**

Let $X$ be a topological space and $A$ a directed set.

A net $\{x_\alpha\}_{\alpha \in A}$ is said to be *convergent* to $x \in X$ (and $x$ is said to be its limit) if for every neighborhood $V$ of $x$ there exists an $\alpha_V \in A$ such that $x_\alpha \in V$ for every $\alpha > \alpha_V$.

**Closed sets characterization**

A set $F$ in a topological space $X$ is closed if and only if and only if every $F$-valued convergent net has its limit in $F$.

#### Proof

We can choose $f$ surjective because even if $Y \setminus f(X) \neq \emptyset$ the hypothesis stays
untouched, because

\begin{equation}
f^{-1}(X \setminus f(X)) = \emptyset
\end{equation}

is indeed a compact set.

Suppose $C \neq \emptyset$ is a closed subset of $X$ such that $f(C)$ is not closed.

Let $\overline{y}$ be a point in $\overline{f(C)} \setminus f(C) \neq \emptyset$ and $\{y_\alpha\}_{\alpha \in A}$ be an $\overline{y}$-convergent net in $f(C)$.

Because every $y_\alpha$ is in $f(C)$ for each one of them we can choose $x_\alpha \in C$ such that $y_\alpha = f(x_\alpha)$ and $\{x_\alpha\}_{\alpha \in A}$ is a net in $C$ convergent to a point in $f^{-1}(\overline{y})$.

Since $C$ is closed, $f^{-1}(\overline{y})$ is compact and they are disjoined, there exists an open set $D \supseteq f^{-1}(\overline{y})$ which is still disjoined from $C$.

We get an absurd because there is no $\alpha \in A$ such that $x_\alpha \in D \supseteq f^{-1}(\overline{y})$ and so $C$ would not be a closed set.

Don't trust this answer until you get a review.

Comment: Why does $\{x_\alpha\}$ converge?

Comment: That question is why I doubted of my answer.

Comment: What you call “lattice” is not what others would call that. It’s an (upwards) directed (pre)order.

Comment: Yes! thank you for noticing it, I forgot to edit it from the conversation above. Actually I was wondering: now that we know that this result is false, do I have to delete this answer or do we keep it as an example of bad proof?